# Strange Threads execution Java

Tags: java, java-threads

I have encountered a strange execution while testing my knowledge about threads haha.

I have the following class:

```
public class ThreadTest {

    public static void main (String[] args){
        Thread t7 = new Thread(() -> {
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                System.out.println("t7 executing...");
            }
            System.out.println("t7 stopped!");
            }
        );
        t7.start();
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            System.out.println("Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...");
        }
        t7.interrupt();
        System.out.println("t7.isInterrupted: " + t7.isInterrupted());
        System.out.println("t7.isInterrupted at finish: " + t7.isInterrupted());
}
```

One the outputs from the execution of the main method was the following:

```
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
.
.
.
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
t7.isInterrupted: true
t7.isInterrupted at finish: false
t7 executing...
t7 stopped!
```

I don't understand why there is also that "t7 executing..." there, since from the outputs I would expect only "t7 stopped!".

Comment: Your code was at the `println("Executing...")` part when it got interrupted, so that code still ran, then the `while` loop checked the status of the interrupt flag, then "stopped" got printed.

Comment: Why do you think that output is not generated by that code?

Comment: @markspace I don't understand how it is possible though, since t7.isInterrupted at finish: false was given in output before "t7 executing" and then "t7 stopped"...

Comment: An interrupt is a flag, it can be set and will be true but the code hasn't actually tested it yet in the `while` loop.

Comment: Why I think that output is not generated by that code? Exactly because of the *errors* you edited: see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPKY8.png)  

Comment: NB `Thread.interrupted()` clears the interrupted status of the thread.

Answer (score -1):

Threading can produce confusing results sometimes, as the concept of threading itself is almost counter-intuitive to the concept of "programming".

Firstly, here is the output I got from executing the code.

```
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
t7 executing...
t7 stopped!
t7.isInterrupted: true
t7.isInterrupted at finish: false
```

You can break down the execution of your statements in a procedural fashion.

You first assign a new object to *t7*, and then flag for its execution with the *start* method.

```java
Thread t7 = new Thread(() -> {
    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
        System.out.println("t7 executing...");
    }
    System.out.println("t7 stopped!");
}
);
t7.start();
```

Then, a *for-loop* will iterate *10* times, printing out some text to the *standard-out*.

```java
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    System.out.println("Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...");
}
```

Generally, you should expect to see different outputs within the *standard-out* here, since there are multiple threads appending data, and the *println* method sets a *lock* on *System#out* when it prints the data.

Here is the source code for *println*.
*[GitHub – jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java#L1166)*.

Continuing further, the *lock* on *System#out* will have been released, so the *t7* thread will print out *"t7 executing..."*.

```java
while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
    System.out.println("t7 executing...");
}
```

Your next statement is an *interrupt* call, to *t7*.
Again, generally you will see mixed results here, in terms of which statement of either thread will be executed first.

For example, you may see it print *"t7 executing..."*, additionally.

```java
t7.interrupt();
```

And, this is followed by two *println* calls.

```java
System.out.println("t7.isInterrupted: " + t7.isInterrupted());
System.out.println("t7.isInterrupted at finish: " + t7.isInterrupted());
```

Your question is,

> *'... I don't understand why there is also that "t7 executing..." there, since from the outputs I would expect only "t7 stopped!".'*

You are implying that the conditional statement for the *t7* *while-loop* will not have been met, thus will skip the code block.

This will vary from each execution, although in this application, you will most likely receive the same result every time.

The reason is because the *for-loop* on your local thread is providing enough time for the *t7* code to execute—they are working concurrently, and not in alternation.

For example, if you increase the *priority* of the *t7* thread, you will see a different result—the default is *5*, of *10*.

```java
t7.setPriority(10);
t7.start();
```

Output

```
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
t7 executing...
t7 executing...
t7 executing...
t7 executing...
t7 executing...
t7 executing...
t7 executing...
t7 executing...
t7 executing...
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
Waiting for t7 to be interrupted...
t7 executing...
t7 stopped!
t7.isInterrupted: true
t7.isInterrupted at finish: false
```

Here is the *Java* tutorial on threading, which will provide some insight to your specific question.
*[Lesson: Concurrency (The Java™ Tutorials > Essential Java Classes)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html)*.